# Grabbing facebook feed in website

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, mobile, feed

I develop mobile websites for my clients. This particular client would like some facebook wall activity to be displayed on the website.  I have looked into the facebook graph api and am getting confused on authentication.

I need the blah in https://graphs.facebook.com/clientsfacebookid/feed?access_token=blah
in order to grab the info i want.  I read about authentication and all of that but it doesn't seem to serve my purposes.. For example a lot of the stuff I read about getting a token is related to creating apps and stuff - which is not what I'm trying to do.  A lot of ways to authenticate redirect users to log in or grant access to the information but this also doesn't seem like it fits my scenario.

Should I just talk to my client and get them to send me an access code or set up some stream so I can grab an updated access code anytime I need it OR is there some built in functionality in the API that I could benefit from using.

Any thoughts?

P.S. I am trying to implement this via an ajax call in javascript.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is create a Facebook App and have your client add this to their page. You can then get an OAuth token for this app and use it to query the client's feed. See the [Facebook documentation for authenticating as an app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) for details.

Comment: I've created an app and received a token.  I can grab information with the token via just typing in https://graphs.facebook.com/clientsfacebookid/feed?access_token=blah into chrome but when I try to do this via javascript I get an invalid Oauth error.  How do I get them to accept my app/ how do I share or publish my app

Comment: One of their page admins needs to add your app. Something is different though. If you can get it from the address bar, you should also be able to get it from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually far simpler if you just want to grab the data from the page. Create an App, but you don't need to add it to the actual page. You can generate an App Access Token by following the [instruction on the Facebook Developer Website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/).

Then, all you need to do is call the Graph API with the generated `access_token`. E.g.:
`https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed?access_token={app_access_token}`

You can then use the data returned by Facebook to display selected posts from the page.

The Page Admin doesn't need to add the app to the page, and this method can be used to scrape any published page. The posts on Pages is public anyway, you just need an `access_token` to access the page.

Comment: User has to log in then, is it possible to show 1 post without logging in?

Comment: Only the person creating the App needs to login to generate the page access token. The user viewing won't ever have to login.

Comment: I don't really get it... Without an access_token, it will not work, how do I get an access token without having to log in?

Comment: You need a page `access_token`. That's different to a user's `access_token`. The page access token can be obtained using the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts). Be sure to choose the correct app and enable the `manage_pages` permission.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple way to learn and have an example of a working model try out [fourgefeed.com](http://fourgefeed.com) its a simple framework with a simple to implement example kinda like jquery.